# How to update the recycler view list of a fragment in a viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Kindly check this app out , if i remove a favorite I'm not able to notify the recycler view instantly. But If i move to the top recipes and get back my viewpager is refreshed. I have tried POSITION_NONE method and I have setTag too. Both of them are not working. Kindly help out in this. Thanks!

Link : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bharatwaaj.android.quickrecipe&hl=en

Comment: add the item to your adapter ArrayList. my_arraylist.add(elementtoadd) then call  adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

Comment: I tried that too, it is not working. Any other ways ?